# Link to directions on Google Maps with one destination prefilled

Tags: google-maps

I want a link on my site which visitors can use to get directions to my location. Is it possible to create a link to a Google Maps directions page, where one end of the directions (the destination) is pre-filled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the origin (Place A) as "current location" and the destination (Place B) as your desired address. Then save that link.

For example:

> **A** current location
>   **B** Sydney Opera House, Sydney Opera House, Bennelong Point, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia

The URL will look something like `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/-33.8592754,151.2096187/Sydney+Opera+House,+Sydney+Opera+House,+Bennelong+Point,+Sydney+NSW+2000,+Australia/@-33.8592754,151.2096187,9z` (there may be more characters, but it will start similarly).

Then change the URL to something else like this:

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/current+location/Sydney+Opera+House,+Sydney+Opera+House,+Bennelong+Point,+Sydney+NSW+2000,+Australia/`

So you'll replace the first set of numbers seen (longitude and latitude) with the string `current+location` and copy all from `https` to just before `@`.

Whenever someone clicks on that link it will start from where they are located, no matter where that is, and show directions to your designated location.

Comment: Nice, but what if it changes (as it already did). Some kind of rule for generating the link would be better.

Comment: 2019 update: You can build links in this structure "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Space+Needle+Seattle+WA&destination=Pike+Place+Market+Seattle+WA&travelmode=bicycling"
Full docs here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action